# useEffect hooks are running to completion BEFORE rendering is completed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render

I am utterly **astounded** that I haven't been able to find more posts about this on stack overflow. Everything about a useEffect hook in react reads that it's supposed to run only after rendering and re-rendering has finished but my hooks are doing the EXACT opposite thing, much to my frustration.

They are all running to completion before I see anything render on my screen whatsoever which goes against everything useEffect hooks are supposed to do.

All I'm trying to do here is have a single button be highlighted/focused when the page loads in.

Here's a very dumbed down version of my useEffect code.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(()=> {

    /* doing a bunch of non-related stuff here. */

    setLoading(false)
    console.log("setLoading to false.")

    
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if(loading == false)
    {
        console.log("Loading verified to be false");
        SpatialNavigation.focus(".onboarding-button-welcome") // this highlights the button.
    }
},[loading])

return (
 <button className="onboarding-button-welcome"> Get Started </button>
)
```

As you can see, the `loading` state variable starts as true for the initial render and is then supposed to then be changed to false by the upper `useEffect`, which causes the lower `useEffect` to fire, check that the loading state variable is false, then focus the button.

My problem (and I've checked this a thousand times with a debugger) is that all of the above is happening **before** I see anything appear on my screen. I see no button until after all the code has run.

The `useEffect` hooks are completing and THEN my render is completing, which means that my `SpatialNavigation.focus()` method is not finding any button to focus in the DOM, which means that the page loads in without the button being highlighted. I never see anything on my screen until all my useEffect hooks have run and that's a major problem because well....

Everything posted everywhere about `useEffect` hooks says this functionality should be impossible since they are only supposed to fire AFTER rendering has completed and the screen has content so what gives here? Like I said, I'm kinda shocked that I haven't seen this question posted on stack overflow because it's a pretty glaring issue as far as React's functionality is concerned.

I should note that I do have a tried and proven albeit hacky way to fix this by wrapping the `SpatialNavigation.focus()` line in a `setTimeout` function but I'd rather not have to do that. I just want the rendering and hooks to trigger in the order that they should be triggering.

***TL;DR***

My simple React code's execution order is somehow:

1. useEffect hooks
2. Rendering the button

and I want it to be (the way it SHOULD be according to React):

1. Rendering the button
2. useEffect hooks

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/28vc1jkf/. Could you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Please consider sharing your own [minimal and **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect hook in React runs after rendering but does not guarantee that rendering is completed before its execution. If you need to interact with a rendered element, use useRef to ensure it's available in the DOM.

```
   import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    /* doing a bunch of non-related stuff here. */

    setLoading(false);
    console.log("setLoading to false.");
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && buttonRef.current) {
      console.log("Button element exists in the DOM, focusing...");
      buttonRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [loading]);

  return (
    <button className="onboarding-button-welcome" ref={buttonRef}>
      Get Started
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  The same behavior as in my original problem.  The useEffect hooks are still being fired before anything has rendered on my screen. I don't think the useRef hook changes anything here.

Comment: code edited try again @ConnorPrice

Comment: Same result.  buttonRef.current is always reading as ```null``` because there is nothing rendered or in the DOM.

This code doesn't change anything as far as the ```useEffect``` hooks firing before rendering has finished. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening before you see anything on the screen because react invokes both `useEffect`'s very very quickly.

`setTimeout`  feels like a good fit for your use case.

Unless you're actually waiting for a response from an async operation, chances are high that both `useEffect`s are going to be invoked near instantaneously.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not doing anything async wise but there's always the chance of a sluggish internet or something along those lines happening which could potentially cause problems down the road with a setTimeout function.

It's still highly annoying that the useEffect hook is basically just straight up lying when it claims to only run after rendering has completed, especially when React claims it doesn't want people to be changing the app while rendering is in process.

Comment: Its not lying. Its just fast. You won't have problems with sluggish internet, because your ```useEffect``` will only be invoked after the initial render. Slow internet may delay the initial render. But on initial render, both hooks will be invoked in quick succession.

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` callback runs after React has finished mutating the DOM, but potentially *before* the browser has finished rendering those mutations to the screen (recomputing page layouts and so forth.)

You're running into a terminology problem, I think -- React generally uses the word "render" to mean running your component render function, and applying the resulting updates to the DOM, but NOT including the browser's work after that, recomputing layouts and repainting the screen. So `useEffect` runs *after* React's "rendering" step, but potentially *before* the browser's layout and paint steps. (This is why you don't see anything on the screen before the effects run.)

(`useLayoutEffect` is similar to `useEffect`, except it guarantees that the effect runs synchronously, still after React does its DOM mutations, but finishing before the browser even starts rendering them. This is good if you want to modify the DOM yourself before that happens.)

For most purposes, this is the right time for your effect callback code to access the DOM. Focusing a field is a classic thing to do in a `useLayoutEffect` (or `useEffect`), because the browser understands `element.focus()` as soon as the element is in the DOM, even if it hasn't finished rendering the element to the screen yet.

For certain unusual purposes, it turns out that this is too soon for an effect to run. If you just need a newly-rendered element to exist, it's fine; but if you need to know things like the position/width/height of the new element, in some cases they may not be computed until the browser has finished rendering the DOM changes to the screen.

I'm not familiar with SpatialNavigation, but I'm guessing it's trying to do something that depends on this kind of information about the new element -- properties that don't exist until after it's done being rendered to the screen.

If what you actually need is "run this code only after the repaint is completely finished", I believe `setTimeout` is actually the correct thing to do. It will run your callback roughly "as soon as the browser has nothing better to do", and I think it's guaranteed to be the soonest you can get code to run while being guaranteed the screen is done updating.

In occasional cases you might even need to run later than that. I personally ran into this issue where the new element was an `iframe`, and I needed to manipulate the contents inside it. In that case, I actually had to wait longer than `setTimeout` -- I ended up hooking the `onLoad` event of the `iframe`, to be sure that the document inside it was completely finished rendering, before poking around inside it.